# How to write an event bus in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, event-sourcing

I am struggling with a design problem in Haskell that I cannot seem to solve in an elegant and satisfying way. I have a system which at its core is based on the concept of **event sourcing**: the state of the system results from the application of a sequence of events to an initial state. There are different types of events, each type being related to a specific component of the system through a type family:

```
class Model a where
   data Event a :: * 
   apply :: Event a -> a -> a

instance Model Foo where
   data Event Foo = Foo Int
   ...

instance Model Bar where
   data Event Bar = Bar String
   ...
```

Currently the system is 100% synchronous and coupled, each model having access to all other model's events and this is quickly becoming a mess, so I want to decouple things through the introduction of an **event bus** `Bus Events` in such a way I should be able to write something like 
`dispatch :: Bus Events -> Consumer (Event Foo) -> Bus Events` to attach some consumer of `Event Foo` to a `Bus Events` assuming there is some form of subtyping or subsumption between `Event Foo` and `Events`.
Then I can add asynchronicity by ensure consumers each run in their own threads.

From a system point of view, this would allow me to ensure each component is independently packagable, limiting dependencies to a subset of all events. `Events` type would be defined at the whole application level. 
This problem looks deceptively similar to discrete-time FRP yet I cannot seem to be able to wrap my head around it...

Has anyone already dealt with something similar and if yes, how?

**EDIT**:

I came up with the following code, which makes no use of `Source` but is greatly inspired by @Cirdec's proposal:

```
import           Control.Applicative
import           Control.Concurrent
import           Control.Concurrent.STM
import           Control.Monad.Reader
import qualified Data.Vector            as V

type Handlers e = V.Vector (Handler e)

data EventBus e = EventBus { handlers    :: Handlers e
                           , eventQueue  :: TChan e
                           , eventThread :: MVar ThreadId
                           }

newBus :: IO (EventBus e)
newBus = do
  chan <- newTChanIO
  var <- newEmptyMVar
  return $ EventBus V.empty chan var

addHandler :: Handler e -> EventBus e -> EventBus e
addHandler h b@EventBus{..} = b { handlers = V.snoc handlers h }

removeHandler :: Int -> EventBus e -> EventBus e
removeHandler idx b@EventBus{..} = b { handlers = let (h,t) = V.splitAt idx handlers
                                                  in h V.++ V.tail t }

startBus :: EventBus e -> IO (EventBus e)
startBus b@EventBus{..} = do
  tid <- forkIO (runBus b)
  putMVar eventThread tid
  return b

runBus :: EventBus e -> IO ()
runBus b@EventBus{..} = do
  _ <- takeMVar eventThread
  forever $ do
    e <- liftIO $ atomically $ readTChan eventQueue
    v <- newTVarIO b
    runReaderT (runEvents $ publish e) v

-- | A monad to handle pub/sub of events of type @e@
newtype Events e a = Events { runEvents :: ReaderT (TVar (EventBus e)) IO a }
                   deriving (Applicative, Functor, Monad, MonadIO, MonadReader (TVar (EventBus e)))

newtype Handler e = Handler { handle :: Events e ()                 -- Unsubscription function
                                     -> Events e (e -> Events e ())  -- what to do with events @e@
                            }


-- | Register a new @Handler e@ within given @Events e@ context
subscribe :: Handler e -> Events e ()
subscribe h = do
  bus <- ask
  liftIO $ atomically $ modifyTVar' bus (addHandler h)

unsubscribe :: Int -> Events e ()
unsubscribe idx = do
  bus <- ask
  liftIO $ atomically $ modifyTVar' bus (removeHandler idx)

publishBus :: EventBus e -> e -> IO ()
publishBus EventBus{..} = atomically . writeTChan eventQueue

publish :: e -> Events e ()
publish event = do
  EventBus{..} <- ask >>= liftIO . atomically . readTVar
  forM_ (zip (V.toList handlers) [0..]) (dispatch event)

dispatch :: e -> (Handler e, Int) -> Events e ()
dispatch event (Handler h, idx) = do
  hdl <- h (unsubscribe idx)
  hdl event

printer :: (Show s) => String -> Handler s
printer prefix = Handler ( \ _ -> return $ \ e -> liftIO (putStrLn $ prefix ++ show e))
```

Comment: so you are searching something like the Observable pattern for your events right? IMO you can implement it just like you would do in OO (using `IORef` or whatever if you want `Subscribe` like behavior - or giving the handlers at creation if you don't want to) - the question is: do you really need it or should your *commands/-handler* be responsible for this?

Comment: @Carsten sort of, yes. For the actual plumbing I plan to use `TChan` which have the nice property of providing pub/sub capabilities, but that's not really my problem. I am more concerned about the overall design approach, this looks like I am trying to implement something like typed actors, or reinvent discrete-time FRP but I am confused.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Your question is asking how to solve a problem a specific way, not how to solve the problem. It's quite possible the solution is something that already exists: oo style events, observables, FRP, or concurrent pipes.

Comment: You are right, my question is specifically on how to implement a specific solution to the general problem of designing "complex" applications in such a way as to reduce coupling and increase cohesion. I have already settled to use event sourcing as the core principle application is based on and my problem is now one of moving from a synchronous (e.g. function-call based) solution to an asynchronous (e.g. event queue, actors,...) based solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An source of events carrying `a`s that can be subscribed to has the following type

```
type Source m a = (a -> m ()) -> m (m ())
                   |             |  ^--- how to unsubscribe             
                   |             ^--- how to subscribe
                   ^--- what to do when an `a` happens
```

A consumer or handler of events is naively something that accepts an event source and subscribes to it

```
type Handler m a = (Source m a             ) -> m ()
                 = ((a -> m ()) -> m (m ())) -> m ()
                                                ^-- set up the consumer.
```

This is a bit convoluted, we can invert things and get a nicer representation for an event handler:

```
type Handler m a = m () -> m (a -> m ())
                   |       |  ^-- what to do when an `a` happens
                   |       ^-- set up the consumer
                   ^-- how to unsubscribe
```

The original event source was a bit tricky to use; a subscriber might want to unsubscribe in response to an event happening, in which case they'd need to recursively get the resulting unsubscribe action into what to do when an event happens. Starting with the nicer definition of a `Handler` we don't have this problem. An event source is now something that accepts an event handler and publishes to it.

```
type Source m a = (Handler m a          ) -> m ()
                = (m () -> m (a -> m ())) -> m ()
                                             ^-- how to subscribe
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this looks like what I am looking for except for one missing part: How to define  a `Handler m a` in such a way that it can be passed to a `Source m b` where `a :< b` for some "sub-typing" relation. But writing that sentence it occurs to me I can simply define `class a :< b` and provide correct instances...

Comment: Actually what I am trying to do does not seem that simple because it would mean being able to coerce some `a` into a sum type `b`, then dispatch to relevant `Handler c` such that `a :< c `. Does not seem to make much sense.